# ExpandabeListView auto collapse

Tags: android

I am not able to close a previously expanded group on expanding a new group. I have read similar questions, but I'm unable to extract concept from them. I tried using the collapseGroup (groupPosition) method, but it is not working.

Answer (score 3):

Hi Please try below code.

---

```
int lastExpandedGroupPosition = 0;   

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final ExpandableListView listView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    listView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (groupPosition != lastExpandedGroupPosition) {
                listView.collapseGroup(lastExpandedGroupPosition);

            }
            lastExpandedGroupPosition = groupPosition;

        }
    });

    adapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, new ArrayList<String>(),
            new ArrayList<ArrayList<Vehicle>>());

    // Set this blank adapter to the list view
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);


}
```

---

import below line.

---

```
import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener;
```

---

Comment: i tried this but not able to implement it on my code...can I get little bit more broad picture of this code..

Comment: One information: if you try to use the above code, and get a "Cannot refer to a non-final variable inside an inner class defined in a different method" error, just create a reference to the listView inside the onGroupExpand() method.

Comment: While this general concept works it's not a great user experience when the previous open group is above the new one you are opening. Everything below the one you collapse, including the one you just expanded, will slide up to fill the space - possibly off the top of the visible ListView if the expanded group had many items.