# how to hide nested layout in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I have an linear layout in my application,In that i am using one root layout(invitation_single) and one nested layout(hidden).when i am onclick root layout at run time the nested layout visible(it contains"yes,no,maybe" buttons)successfully.Now my need is if i have similar layout values(consider event 2)  immediately below the previous layout values(consider event 1),when i am on click "event 2" i need to hide nested layout of "event 1"(atpresent when i am click button the nested layout gone)automatically.how can i achieve this..here is my layout code,

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/invitation_single"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="?android:dividerVertical"
    android:dividerPadding="5dp"
    android:showDividers="middle"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_event" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/invitation_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="0dp"
            android:paddingTop="3dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/invitation_place"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="0dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/hidden"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-270dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:weightSum="3">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/yesbutton"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/blue"
            android:text="Yes"
            android:textColor="@color/black"></Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nobutton"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/blue"
            android:text="No"
            android:textColor="@color/black"></Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonmaybe"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/blue"
            android:text="Maybe"
            android:textColor="@color/black"></Button>

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

my programming code is below,

```
final LinearLayout first = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.invitation_single);
final LinearLayout second = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.hidden);
first.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.invitation_single:
                second.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: What do you want exactly make it clear

Comment: can you please check this "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31893126/how-to-close-nested-layout-when-open-new-layout-in-android"i gave detail expectation on this

Comment: did you check that post?

Comment: Yes I did checked that but i want it in simple way

Comment: the first  images of that post explained ,if i am onclick "event 1" the three buttons are shown immediately below,consider if have "event 2"  when i am onclick that event the buttons of previous layout needs to be hide..that is my need.

Comment: So you want to show 3 btns when i click 1st event btn and when i click event2 btn i want to hide them

Comment: will you have more than two events?

Comment: yeah i have more than two events

Comment: then better you go for the ExpandableListView with custom adapter,

Answer (score 1):

is this what you're looking for?

```
first.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.invitation_single:
                second.setVisibility(second.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: can you please look this link i gave my requirements in that link"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31893126/how-to-close-nested-layout-when-open-new-layout-in-android"

Comment: Do  you have a small set of events or the number of events could get pretty long? If the second choice is true then I would suggest looking at ExpandableListView. Check out this link particularly on how to collapse the previously open items upon expanding a new one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6043339/expandabelistview-auto-collapse